# Deploying to Heroku gets stuck on "Resolving dependencies......"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been able to deploy to Heroku without issue for months, but as of a week ago it's been getting stuck within seconds of starting.

Once deployment reaches 'Resolving dependencies........' it just hangs. And I have not added any new gems to my app since my last successful deployments.

This is what I get after an hour or so when it times out:

```
remote: Resolving dependencies...........

remote: error: fatal: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've contacted Heroku but they just requested help from the build team, who never showed up. Anyone else run into this before?

Comment: If you try to deploy your last working commit deployed to heroku, does it work?

Comment: How can I find the last working commit for a deployment? I can see my git history, but aren't really sure which one came before my last deploy.